# Trigger Rundeck Job via API

Tags: rundeck

Rundeck supports triggering jobs via their API. The API documentation is available under [documentation](http://rundeck.org/docs/api/index.html#running-a-job).

We are using API version 13 which does not yet support application/json. Therefore i need to use the XML based request.

In my previous attempts, i always get the response:

`<result error="true" apiversion="13">
   <error code="api.error.job.options-invalid">
     <message>Job options were not valid: Option 'container' is required. Option 'version' is required.
     </message>
   </error>
</result>`

Since there is no example request provided, i am searching for an example payload to trigger the job.

As seen in the response i have to provide the parameters "container" and "version" since they are required.

My most recent request payload was:

`<executeJob>
    <argString>-container containerName -version 1234567</argString>
</executeJob>`

I also tried different variations of this payload, every time with the same response.

Answer (score 11):

This should help you, assuming you have a token to access Rundeck with authorization to run the job

```
curl -D - -X "POST" -H "Accept: application/json" \
    -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
    -H "X-Rundeck-Auth-Token: <TOKEN>" \
    -d '{"argString":"-arg1 val1 -arg2 val2"}' \
http://<URL>/api/16/job/<JOB_ID>/executions
```

Comment: This helped tremendously. I was able to take this and use it for a webhook URL in Grafana 9 alerting. I just used "https://myrundeck/api/41/job/<job-id-here>/executions?authtoken=<token>" for the webhook and it worked great. :)